# How to Fetch Records from CloudKit Not in My Local Cache

Tags: cloudkit

I have an app that uses CloudKit for sync and I maintain a local cache of records. I have run into a sync scenario that I can't figure out.

I'm using the **Public database** and when my app is opened, I want to be able to go get all the updated records that my app missed while it was closed, or on a device where the app was just installed.

I can get the **updated** records by creating a `NSPredicate` to compare the `modificationDate` like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "modificationDate > %@", syncTimestamp as CVarArg) 
let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: predicate)
```

But the part I can't figure out is **how to get only the records that have been added to, or removed from, the CloudKit server**.

Does anyone know how to do this? I know Apple provides a way for this in the Private database but I'm using the Public one here.

The only thing I can think of so far is to query *all the reocrds* of a certain `recordType`, collect all their `recordName`s and compare to my local cache. But it'd be nice to have smarter way than just pull large amounts of data and comparing huge arrays of `recordName`s.

Answer (score 0):

`CKQuerySubscription(recordType: myRecordType, predicate: predicate, options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordDeletion])` works perfectly on **public** DB.

Here's a code snippet (saving subscription is done with *RxCloudKit*, but this is beyond the point) -

```html
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")

// the options are different from what you need, just showcasing the possibilities:
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: recordTypeTest, predicate: predicate, options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion, .firesOnce])

let info = CKNotificationInfo()
info.alertLocalizationKey = "NEW_PARTY_ALERT_KEY"
info.soundName = "NewAlert.aiff"
info.shouldBadge = true

subscription.notificationInfo = info

self.publicDB.rx.save(subscription: subscription).subscribe { event in
    switch event {
    case .success(let subscription):
        print("subscription: ", subscription)
    case .error(let error):
        print("Error: ", error)
    default:
        break
    }
}.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have subscriptions working already, and, for the most part, they keep my app data up-to-date. The scenario I’m trying to handle is how to fetch the changes the app missed if it didn’t get the most recent notifications (like, if the user was on an airplane for the last 5 hours and missed 20 notifications). I want to fetch what changed in the database.

Comment: `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` with previous token does not work on public DB?..

Comment: No, as I understand it, it’s only available in **private** and **shared** databases.